# Can't imports be on shared drives?

Tags: python, import, anaconda, libraries

I have a shared drive where I have my python code, and Python is installled on my C drive.

Using the `anaconda` command prompt, if I run on my shared drive, `pip install requests` it says `Requirement already satisfied` and shows where I have this library in my C drive.

But my code in the shared drive won't run because it says `No module named 'requests'`, so it clearly doesn't know how to see my installed libraries.

Do I need to run my Python code in my C drive or can I somehow point my code to look in the C drive for the libraries?

Comment: Shared drives are not special. Any directory works. You have some other problem, but there is not enough information to say what it is.

Comment: What do you have in your ENV variables as PATH?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into using virtual python environments.

https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

In your share drive, (assuming your python3, you should be able to do something like this)

```
h:\pycode> python3 -m venv env
h:\pycode> .\env\Scripts\activate
```

once you have activated your virtual environment, install the necessary libraries (ideally by listing them in *requirements.txt*) and running `pip install -r requirements.txt`